# Original Formulation of Hilbert's 14th Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, math-history, invariant-theory

I have a problem seeing how the original formulation of Hilbert's 14th Problem is "the same" as the one found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fourteenth_problem). Hopefully someone in here can help me with that. Let me quote Hilbert first:

> Es sei eine Anzahl $m$ von ganzen rationalen Funktionen $X_1,\dots,X_m$ der $n$ Variablen $x_1,\dots,x_n$ vorgelegt:
>   \begin{equation}\begin{split}X_1&=f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\&\vdots\\X_m&=f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n).\end{split}\end{equation}
>   (He calls this system of substitutions (S)). Jede ganze rationale Verbindung von $X_1,\dots,X_m$ wird offenbar durch Eintragung dieser Ausdrücke notwendig stets eine ganze rationale Funktion von $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Es kann jedoch sehr wohl gebrochene rationale Funktionen von $X_1,\dots,X_m$ geben, die nach Ausführung jener Substitution (S) zu ganzen Funktionen in $x_1,\dots,x_n$ werden. Eine jede solche rationale Funktion von $X_1,\dots,X_m$, die nach Ausführung der Substitution (S) ganz in $x_1,\dots,x_n$ wird, möchte ich eine relativganze Funktion von $X_1,\dots,X_m$ nennen. Jede ganze Funktion von $X_1,\dots,X_m$ ist offenbar auch relativganz; ferner ist die Summe, die Differenz und das Produkt relativganzer Funktionen stets wiederum relativganz.
>
> Das entstehende Problem ist nun: zu entscheiden, ob es stets möglich ist, ein endliches System von relativganzen Funktionen von $X_1,\dots,X_m$ aufzufinden, durch die sich jede andere relativganze Funktion in ganzer rationaler Weise zusammensetzen läßt.

Okay, unfortunately this is in German. Here's what I made out of it, but can't guarantee it is right:

> Start with $f_1,\dots,f_m\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ for some field $k$. For every $g\in k[X_1,\dots,X_m]$, $g(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ is then a polynomial in the $x_i$. But there can be $\varphi\in k(X_1,\dots,X_m)$ such that $\varphi(f_1,\dots,f_m)\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, which Hilbert calls "relativganz". Every polynomial in the $X_i$ is of course already relativganz, as well as sum, difference, and product of functions which are relativganz.
>
> The problem: Is it always possible to find finitely many r-g functions $g_1,\dots,g_s$ in $k(X_1,\dots,X_m)$ such that every r-g function $\varphi$ can be expressed in the $g_i$ in a polynomial way?

Now the formulation as it is mentioned on wikipedia:

> Let $k$ be a field, and $K\subseteq k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a subfield. Is the ring $R=K\cap k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ finitely generated as a ring?

So, as for the original formulation, we can choose $R$ to be the ring of r-g functions. But what is $K$ in this case? I feel like the choice of $f_1,\dots,f_m$ should correspond one-to-one to the choice of the subfield $K$. Is it possible, given the second formulation, to translate this back to the notion of "relativganz", i.e., can I always interpret $R$ as a ring of r-g functions? Are they really equivalent?

Sorry for the many question in this last paragraph, but I want to really understand how to translate between those two seemingly different formulations :-)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I only corrected some umlauts and hyphens; your paraphrase of the German passage is correct.

Comment: @joriki Thank you! I must have become confused with the hyphens, since Hilbert uses both ways himself. My concern with this passage was not the actual translation German->English, since I'm German, but rather if I screwed up in translating the 'content' ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two formulations are indeed equivalent.

The map $f: k(X_1,...,X_m) \rightarrow k(x_1,...,x_n)$ that sends $X_i$ to $f_i$ is an injection of fields. It identifies $k(X_1,...,X_m)$ with a subfield $K$ of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$. The intersection $R=K\cap k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is then all elements of $k(X_1,..,X_m)$ that are mapped to $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ via $f$, i.e. exactly the relatinganz functions (relative to f).

It's a fact that any subfield $K$ of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$ is finitely generated. To recover Hilbert's formulation, we only need to choose generators $f_1,...,f_m$ for $K$ (over $k$). Note that the notion of being relativganz depends only on the field $K$ generated by the $f_i$, not the individual generators.

Comment: Hello @Prometheus, and thanks for the response. I already forgot about this, because I now knew that I just interpreted the German passage in a wrong way, that is, I was thinking about a map $k(y_1,\dots,y_m)\to k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ sending $y_i\mapsto X_i=f_i$, which would not be well-defined at all. Instead, Hilbert directly talks about the subfield $k(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ of the rational function field.

Comment: But I still had/have a slight problem with the equivalence which you could maybe explain to me (even though I already accepted your answer for the sake of completeness ;)): I know that every subfield $K$ of $k(x_1\dots,x_n)$ is f.g., that is, $K=k(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)$ for $\varphi_i\in k(x)$. But Hilbert takes the $\varphi_i$ (his $f_i$) to be polynomials, not rational functions. I'm pretty sure that this doesn't make any difference after intersecting with the polynomial ring, but the argument doesn't seem trivial to me, since not every $K$ is $k(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ with polynomial $f_i$'s.

Comment: Suppose the statement is true when the subfield is generated by polynomials. If $K$ is any subfield of $K(x_1,...,x_n)$, let $K′$ be the field generated by $R=K \cap k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Then $K'\cap k[x_1,...,x_n]=R$, so it's enough to show the statement holds for $K′$. I claim $K′$ is generated by finitely many polynomials in $R$. Since $K′$ is finitely generated over $k$, $K′=k(f′_1,...,f'_l)$. $K′$ is generated by $R$, so each $f′_i$ is a rational function in elements of $R$: $f′_i=g_i/h_i$, with $g_i,h_i \in R$. Then since $R \subset K′$, $K′=k(g_1,...,g_l,h_1,...,h_l)$.